# How to display the stack integer values on the output screen using method overriding?

Tags: c++

Recently my lab instructor gave me the following code on stacks to run, by using the concept of method overriding (we are studying inheritance at the moment):

```cpp
//4.3. This example demonstrates that how we can use the concept of Overriding.
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

class myStack {
protected:  //NOTE: Can't be private because only my child class should have access to it
    enum {
        maximumnumberofboxes = 3 
    }; // enumerated is used before a user defined variable (maximumnumberofboxes) that contains a collection of built in datatypes. 
    //I have used it to tell the size of my stack array
    int stack[maximumnumberofboxes]; // my stack array of integers
    int topvalue;
    //Index to top of stack. An index accesses a specific element in my stack array (in this case, the top value)

public:
    Stack() //my stack constructor
    {
        topvalue = -1;  
    }

    void push(int valueinbox) //Define a function that pushes the value of a specific element in the stack space
    {
        stack[++topvalue] = valueinbox; //put the value on stack
    }

    int pop()  //Define a function that pulls off the value of a specific element in the stack space
    {
        return stack[topvalue--]; //take number off stack
    }

};


class childStack : public myStack //Single Inheritance
{
public:
    void push(int valueinbox)
    { //put the value on stack
        if(topvalue >= maximumnumberofboxes-1) //error if stack full
        {
            cout<<"topvalue = "<<valueinbox;
            cout<<"\ntopvalue= "<<topvalue;
            cout << "\nError: stack is full";
            exit(1);
        }
        cout<<"\ntopvalue= "<<topvalue;
        cout<<"\ntopindex= "<<valueinbox;

        myStack::push(valueinbox); //call push() function in myStack class using unary scope operator
    }

    int pop() //call pop() function to pull value off my stack
    {
        if(topvalue < 0) //shows error if my stack is empty
        { 
            cout << "\nError: stack is empty\n";
            exit(1);
        }
        return myStack::pop(); //call pop() in myStack class
    }

};

int main()
{
    childStack s1;
    s1.push(11); //push some values onto child stack
    s1.push(22);
    s1.push(33);

    cout << endl << s1.pop(); //pop some values from child stack
    cout << endl << s1.pop();
    cout << endl << s1.pop();
    cout << endl << s1.pop(); //oops, popped one too many...
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

my output screen displays the following:

```
topvalue=11
topvalue=4249067
Error: stack is full
```

I want to know how can I display the three integers mentioned in the main function (11,22,33) on the output screen without getting any garbage value?

Comment: OT: conio.h? Interesting... which system are you on?

Comment: If you can, check every line starting from `s1.push(11);` with a debugger and see what's in your stack.

Comment: Other than a possible typo: `Stack() //my stack constructor` should be `myStack() //my stack constructor`, I can compile and run your program, and I get the expected `33\n22\n11\n` output.

Comment: If you copy-paste your code in an online compiler with the typo fixed, as mentioned by @Adrian-ReinstateMonica , it seems to work as you'd expect.

Comment: Without the correction, your code *shouldn't* compile, unless your compiler uses the "C-style" ***default int*** for the function `Stack()`. In this case, you will not be calling the 'constructor' you think you have, and then you'll probably get the behaviour you describe. (To reproduce on other compilers, just add `void ` before `Stack()`. This gives ***undefined behaviour*** as `topValue` is uninitialized.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a couple problems with your code :

1. I assume `Stack()` meant to be the constructor of class `myStack` right? Well to achieve that it has to have the same name as your class (`myStack()`). I'm not sure how this code compiled on your machine.
2. You don't initialize your array `int stack[maximumnumberofboxes]`. so at the start it will probably have some garbage value in it.

**Note:** On this line `cout << endl << s1.pop(); //oops, popped one too many...` your program will exit so you wont be able to reach `system("pause");` and see what is actually printed on your console.